# Css div absolute surrounded by text

Tags: html, text, css-position, absolute, surround

I am trying to surround div with position: absolute by text.
Always text going under div.

CSS which I am using:

```
.all {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 180px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #fa65fc;
}
.abs {
    position: absolute;
    top:  80px;
    left: 200px;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4542df;
}
```

Two divs:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="abs">ABS</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

Here is link to: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5Pg5/1/)

I would like to do something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible with absolutely positioned div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the result you are looking for by using css to insert a dummy element. This method means you do not need to position your `<div class="abs">` within the middle of the content of that div. This may be of use if you are not able to control what the content is (in the case of content being entered in a cms).

HTML:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="abs">ABS</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 180px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #fa65fc;
}

.all:before { 
    content: "";
    float: right;
    height: 80px;
    width: 0;
}

.abs {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4542df;
}
```

Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrianlynch/U5Pg5/3/).

`.all:before` inserts a dummy element which is floated right, no width and 80px high at the very beginning of `<div class="all">`.

Because `.abs` is floated right (but not positioned absolute), it will now try and stay floated right at the top of the div. Adding `clear: both` forces it drop below any other floated elements, so it ends up moving 80px down to clear the dummy float before it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is it what I need :)))) Because I am using WordPress, I cannot control text before and after div.

Comment: This is a nice method I was not aware of, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with position absolute. However you can achieve what you show on your image using static position and `float: right;` with some margins.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5Pg5/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="all">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
<div class="abs">ABS</div>
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 180px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #fa65fc;
}
.abs {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #4542df;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about image, but this solutions for me is not good, because this text will be generated.